# Bitwise operations evaluating to long

Tags: c#, casting, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, logical-operators

I've been converting some Java code to C# and ran into a little pickle. All the documentation on MSDN suggests that all bitwise operations return the type that is being operated on. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691307(v=vs.71).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691377(v=vs.71).aspx but what ever I do my intellisense keeps telling me that you "Cannot implicitly convert type 'long' to 'int'." The following line is the one with the issue and to me, all the literals in there look like they evaluate to int's and all the operated types are either int's or uint's. What am I missing? I don't even declare any long variables in my file and all the variables below are of type int. The casting to uint is to preserve the unsigned bit-shift operator of java (>>>)

```
int t1 = ((s13 << 96 - 66) | ((uint)s12 >> 66 - 64)) ^ ((s13 << 96 - 93) | ((uint)s12 >> 93 - 64));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When uint is operated with int the result is long. naturally.

```
int t1 = (int)((((uint)s13 << 96 - 66) | ((uint)s12 >> 66 - 64)) ^ (((uint)s13 << 96 - 93) | ((uint)s12 >> 93 - 64)));
```

Note: c# compiler is *smart* and can deal with constants. so (uint)s | 1 is uint because it can determine that statically.

Comment: Exactly *which* part of the expression causes the promotion to long?

Comment: This part does: `((s13 << 96 - 66) | ((uint)s12 >> 66 - 64))`

Comment: So then `int | uint -> long`? (It's more subtle than that though, it seems. Using *int* literals changes the behavior.)

Comment: `uint | 1 -> uint`. So confusing C# compiler!

Comment: @Rohit turns out the inner casting isn't required. Simply casting the entire expression to int works as well!

Comment: Coming back to this the behaviour is actually expected an not confusing. When you have a positive int literal that is too large for an int but would fit in a uint, it will automatically take that literal and make it a uint. However if you add a int and a uint, to maintain the signed nature of the int, the compiler takes the next largest signed type, which is a long. This way it maintains the signed-ness of the int, and knows that it can fit the uint!

Comment: @jduncanator: There are some twists in this behavior, though.  Subtracting a compile-time constant of type `int` which happens to be positive to a `UInt32` will yield a result of type `UInt32`, even though the result might trap or wrap.  If the constant happens to be negative, the result will be of type `Int64`, even though the result is guaranteed to be positive.